# Ui testing of Silverlight Control datePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, datepicker, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to automate UI tests to my Silverlight App with Visual Studio 2010. I have one `dataPicker` on my app. Whem I'm playing the recording actions, the date is not selected.

It returns the error:

```
Test method CriarRequisicao3.comparar5.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException: 
Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. 

Additional Details: 

TechnologyName:  'Silverlight'
ControlType:     'Button'
AutomationId:   'Button'

 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F003"

The code that VS2010 generate for this step is:

// Select '18-Nov-2011' in 'dp_DesiredDate' date picker

uIDp_DesiredDateDatePicker.SelectedDateAsString = this.RecordedMethod14Params.UIDp_DesiredDateDatePickerSelectedDateAsString;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere that the datepicker control had known issues. I can't seem to find the link for it at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

Need more code to answer you question, actually, but from the exception I can suggest that your code tries to click on datepicker calendar without actually having it shown.
So you must add some code to make datepicker appear, and then select date.